# Choleskey Decomposition in C++ via Lapack dpotrf gives invalid result

Tags: c++, matrix, lapack, matrix-factorization, lapacke

I'm trying to take the choleskey decomposition of a 1D double array using Lapack's dpotrf function.
It seems to work for some cases, but others it has strange behavior.

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    int N=2;
    int INFO;
    double A2 [2*2] = {
            1,1,
            1,4
        };
        printf("%f %f\n", A2[0], A2[1]);
        printf("%f %f\n", A2[2], A2[3]);
        printf("\n");

    char UPLO='L';
    LAPACK_dpotrf(&UPLO,&N,A2,&N,&INFO);

    printf("%f %f\n", A2[0], A2[1]);
    printf("%f %f\n", A2[2], A2[3]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("2x2 working?: ");
    printf("%i\n",INFO);

// double A3 [3*3] = {
    //     1,1,1,
    //     1,1,1,
    //     1,1,4
    // };

  double A3 [3*3] = {
        2,-1, 0,
        -1, 2, -1, 
        0, -1, 2
        };

    printf("%f %f %f\n", A3[0], A3[1], A3[2]);
    printf("%f %f %f\n", A3[4], A3[5], A3[6]);
    printf("%f %f %f\n", A3[7], A3[8], A3[9]);
    printf("\n");

    int N3=3;
    LAPACK_dpotrf(&UPLO,&N3,A3,&N3,&INFO);

    printf("%f %f %f\n", A3[0], A3[1], A3[2]);
    printf("%f %f %f\n", A3[4], A3[5], A3[6]);
    printf("%f %f %f\n", A3[7], A3[8], A3[9]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("%i\n",INFO);
    

    return 0;
}
```

and is built via:

```
g++ main.cpp -lblas -llapack -llapacke
```

The 2x2 case gives:

```
1.000000 1.000000
1.000000 1.732051
```

Technically, this is incorrect, as it isn't lower triangular, but the lower part is correct

It correctly (perhaps by accident), identifies that it cannot operate on the commented out A3 matrix.

It correctly indicates that it can operate on the valid A3, but the resulting value is:

```
1.414214 -0.707107 0.000000
1.224745 -0.816497 0.000000
-1.000000 1.154701 0.000000
```

The valid Cholesky decomposition is (according to Matlab):

```
1.4142         0         0
-0.7071    1.2247        0
      0   -0.8165    1.1547
```

I suspect the function is not broken, but I don't have the right arguments.
I suspect it might be the LDA variable, as I have no idea what this is, and other LAPACK functions typically just have this set to the same value of N.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is incorrect, as it isn't lower triangular

It is correct since the original data in the upper triangular is not overwritten.

In the 3x3 case you are printing the wrong elements. Take a close look.

Comment: I think it might have been just that simple.  A bit oddly, the solver seems to give an upper triangular matrix with UPLO='L', although this might be a plotting artifact as well.